# Returning a boolean in .map() does not have same behavior as in for() loop?

Tags: javascript

Is there a difference in using `.map()` and `for()` when returning a boolean? See code example where the `for()` loop returns true, but the `.map()` returns nothing.

```
function simpleLoop(theArray) {
    // Works as expected
    for (var i = theArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        let value = anObject[theArray[i]];

        if (!value || /^\s*$/.test(value)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

function simpleMap(theArray) {
    // Does not work
    theArray.map((language) => {
        const value = anObject[language];

        if (!value || /^\s*$/.test(value)) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}

simpleLoop(theArray) // <-- returns true
simpleMap(theArray) // <-- returns nothing (?)
```

Comment: That `return` is in the callback function, `simpleMap` has no `return` statement.

Comment: When you `return` inside the `for` loop, you are returning from the `simpleLoop` function. When you return inside `map`, you return from the anonymous function.

Comment: @Tholle and how would you make the simpleMap return it then? Or is this not possible?

Comment: `map()` is wrong method also if all you want is to see if a value exists

Comment: @NealVDV I would use `some` instead of `map`, and return that from `simpleMap`.

Comment: `return theArray.map()` obv to return the result after mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you return inside the `for` loop, you are returning from the `simpleLoop` function. When you return inside `map`, you return from the anonymous function given to `map`.
I would use `some` instead of `map` to get the desired effect:

```
function simpleSome(theArray) {
    return theArray.some((language) => {
        const value = anObject[language];
        return !value || /^\s*$/.test(value);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`simpleMap` isn't returning anything – it's simply creating an array.

Although @Thoelle's answer is what I'd recommend as the cleanest solution, for the sake of exhausting all options, here is a way you *could* accomplish what you want using the `map()` function:

```
function simpleMap(theArray) {
  const localArray = theArray.map((language) => {
    const value = anObject[language];

    if (!value || /^\s*$/.test(value)) {
        return true;
    }
  });

  return localArray.indexOf(true) > -1;
}
```

Comment: Yes it is, now I understand that it is just creating a new array with the modified values, thanks

Comment: @NealVDV no...it is not modifying the original array at all

Comment: What @charlietfl ^ said. It's actually creating a new array – but the array is not being used because it's not being assigned to anything or returned from the function.

Answer (score 0):

`map` function *doesn't* modify the array. It is **immutable** operation. Map functions transform the array and it returns a new Array. In your case, you are not returning the **modified** array. You need to return the test condition outside the `map` callback function.

```
function simpleMap(theArray) {
    // Does not work
    var newArray = theArray.map((language) => {
        const value = anObject[language];

        if (!value || /^\s*$/.test(value)) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    // Return array or your condition.
    return newArray ;
}
```

Comment: will return undefined on other elements in array. Rather doubt that is what OP is trying to accomplish

Comment: @charlietfl you are right, That's the reason, I added the comment to ` // Return array or your condition.` to ensure that  OP can return based on the condition needed.